# Need distinct combine count in SQL Server without temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server.

I have an employee table and I need to relocate some of my employees such that they work together. Basically I want to shift my department and it's specialist in 1 place. So if IT Dept has java specialists working from different locations they need to be bought to 1 place

I need to know the list where in 1 department have same specialists based on 2 locations

My employee table has 4 columns

- ID
- Department
- Specialization
- Location

| Id | Dept | Specialist | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | IT | Java Lang | London |
| 110 | IT | Java Lang | London |
| 125 | IT | Java Lang | Paris |
| 128 | IT | Java Lang | Paris |
| 130 | IT | Java Lang | Paris |
| 135 | IT | Python | India |
| 140 | IT | Python | India |
| 145 | Accounts | Audit | London |
| 150 | Accounts | Audit | London |
| 150 | Accounts | Audit | London |

Output

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IT | Java | Paris |
| IT | Java | London |

Please help and pardon me the table format was not getting copied

Comment: instead of copying the data, take a snapshot and try pasting it here. Unable to understand the question. If possible also let us know what is the expected output in a snapshot as well.

Comment: @NNM I suggest you the following post where are tools to paste the data instead using a snapshot (is not recommended and we don't recommend it as well) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please find the snapshot

Comment: @JavaBhai please read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and edit your question

Comment: `select distinct Dept, Specialist, Location from T t1 where exists (select 1 from T t2 where t2.Dept = t1.Dept and t2.Specialist = t2.Specialist and t2.Location <> t1.Location)`

Comment: Thanks a ton @shawnt00, I was struggling since long, just was not able to think though, it was sweet and short query

Answer (score 1):

You can use a windowed count for this

```sql
SELECT
  t.Dept,
  t.Specialist,
  t.Location
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.Dept,
      t.Specialist,
      t.Location,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Dept, t.Specialist) count
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY
      t.Dept,
      t.Specialist,
      t.Location
) t
WHERE t.count > 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=15ae710ea7b1782ee4c988fc8ba7d0d4)

Comment: thanks it works perfectly @charlieface